# Empty Parameter For GRPC service method

Tags: reactjs, go, grpc, grpc-go

I am a beginner in golang and GRPC. I am trying to use React as frontend , GRPC instead of API and GoLang as backend.
I am just trying to pass two int64 parameter in add() service and return the sum but the parameter is always 0 when i try to log in server.

service.proto

```
syntax = "proto3";
package main;
option go_package="./pingpong";

message PingRequest {

}

message PongResponse {
    bool ok = 1;
}

message AdditionRequest {
    int64 param1 = 2;
    int64 param2 = 3;
}

message AdditionResponse {
    int64 output = 4;
}

service PingPong{
    rpc Ping(PingRequest) returns (PongResponse) {};
    rpc Add(AdditionRequest) returns (AdditionResponse) {};
}
```

server.go

```
        package handler

    import (
        "context"
        "log"

        "github.com/sibesh/react-go/pingpong"
    )

    // Server is the Logic handler for the server
    // It has to fullfill the GRPC schema generated Interface
    // In this case its only 1 function called Ping
    type Server struct {
        pingpong.UnimplementedPingPongServer
    }

    // Ping fullfills the requirement for PingPong Server interface
    func (s *Server) Ping(ctx context.Context, ping *pingpong.PingRequest) (*pingpong.PongResponse, error) {
        log.Println("Server Requested")
        return &pingpong.PongResponse{
            Ok: true,
        }, nil
    }

    // Ping fullfills the requirement for PingPong Server interface
    func (s *Server) Add(ctx context.Context, request *pingpong.AdditionRequest) (*pingpong.AdditionResponse, error) {
        output := request.GetParam1() + request.GetParam2()
        log.Println("Get Param1: ")
        log.Println(request.GetParam1())
        return &pingpong.AdditionResponse{
            Output: output,
        }, nil
    }
```

Calculator.js

```
  let calculate = function (client, param1, param2) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    try {

      let additionRequest = new AdditionRequest(param1, param2);
      client.add(additionRequest, null, function (err, response) {
        let pong = response.toObject();
        resolve(pong);
      });
    } catch (e) {
      reject(e);
    }
  });
};

calculate(this.client, this.state.param1, this.state.param2)
  .then((results) => {
    console.log(results);
    this.setState(results);
    this.forceUpdate();
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

Output in server console

```
2021/04/25 13:04:08 Get Param1: 
2021/04/25 13:04:08 0
```

Output in browser console

[image]
[image]

Even i have sent parameters i.e 10 and 20, i get 0 in server side. Please help me guys. Looking for somekind of help or hints.

Comment: are you using grpc-web client? https://github.com/grpc/grpc-web

Comment: yep i am already using that. I get the server response as well but the parameter is not correctly fetch @Shaikhul

Comment: is `AdditionRequest` a protobuf request or your custom function? at what point you set the params (ex. setParam1 and setParam2) with the request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually i should have used setParam1 & setParam2 to set values like below:

```
    let calculate = function (client, param1, param2) {
return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    try {

    let additionRequest = new AdditionRequest();
     additionRequest.setParam1(param1);
     additionRequest.setParam2(param2);
    client.add(additionRequest, null, function (err, response) {
        let pong = response.toObject();
        resolve(pong);
    });
    } catch (e) {
    reject(e);
    }
});
};
```